# Как плавно завершить анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

Как плавно завершить анимацию, то есть создать эффект, что колесо выкатилось при скролле и плавно остановилось ?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
    $('.wheel').addClass("active-left");
  } else {};
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

footer {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.wheel {
  animation: infinite-spinning 150ms steps(8) infinite;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  left: -250px;
  transition: all 3s ease
}

.wheel.active-left {
  left: 0;
  animation: infinite-spinning 250ms steps(8) 16;
}

@-webkit-keyframes infinite-spinning {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  прокрути вниз
</header>
<div class="wheel">
  <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/car_wheel/2-2-car-wheel-png-picture.png" alt="wheel">
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
    $('.wheel').addClass("active-left");
  } else {};
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: green;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

footer {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.wheel {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-250px, 0);
}

.wheel.active-left {
  animation: infinite-spinning 3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes infinite-spinning {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-250px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  прокрути вниз
</header>
<div class="wheel">
  <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/car_wheel/2-2-car-wheel-png-picture.png" alt="wheel">
</div>
<footer>

</footer>
```